# Is the Platform by Cartalyst made for Laravel framework?

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentinel

I have came across [Platform by Cartalyst](https://cartalyst.com/manual/platform/4.0) package, is this platform sits on the top of Laravel 5.1 or is it it's own framework?

Comment: *"Platform is essentially just a series of components that work with Laravel 5.1."* (found this right after my other comment. overlooked it)

Comment: @CayceK thanks alot for your input. Have you used it? is it worth the subscription? will it help me when developing large application?

Comment: hard to say.. Depends on your  experience. If you have an extensive knowledge of laravel than working in Laravel may be faster than using this. But I have never used it. so I don't know positives. I shy away from things with subscriptions that doesn't let me use the code as a test to see if I'm going to like it. I also am one to prefer typing my own stuff a lot.

Comment: @CayceK, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct quote from their page

> Platform is essentially just a series of components that work with Laravel 5.1.

So yes. It looks like just a bunch of functions created for laravel 5.1 framework. Functions/libraries that you would most likely do it your self if you were to start from scratch.

Library like this saves you time and time is money. Although this requires a subscription, I think you may still end up saving money if you were to write your own code. This will let you skip the most boilerplate stuff (templates, acl etc) and start working on your project.

On the other hand, you do not know the code unless you go through it. You are using someone else's code in your own project. It is up to you to decide basically.